# Why does python only run a single test_method in my TestCase?

Tags: python, unit-testing, sublimetext2, indentation

I have a set of unit tests that look basically like this:

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

    def test_two(self):
        self.assertEqual(2,2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

When I run the tests, I would expect to see results from both test_methods (test_one and test_two), but I only get results for one:

```
$ python -m unittest -v tests.test_dummy
test_one (tests.test_dummy.MyTestCase) ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.6

(This text added to make my comment long enough.)

Comment: Cannot replicate, works in pycharm and when run from the command line

Comment: 2.7.3 shows two tests

Comment: This is mystifying to me. I get the same result on 2.6. I'm running Mac OS X 10.10.4 with python installed through anaconda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, this is mortifying.

It was an indentation problem. The test file had a combination of tabs and spaces, so the second test wasn't being identified.

I copied the invisible glitch from my real code, to the simplified MyTestCase class I used to replicate the error. But stackoverflow stripped out the tabs, so no one else was able to replicate.

Here's the bug that was killing my code. Tabs are shown with hyphens: ----

```
import unittest

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_one(self):
        self.assertEqual(1,1)

----def test_two(self):
--------self.assertEqual(2,2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: You should get a proper text editor (like Notepad++, or Sublime), they deal with tab/space mixed code. It's the only sane option.

Comment: I'm using Sublime 2, which is partly why I was so surprised this happened.

Comment: That's really weird. Did you change any settings? Is your file saved as *.py*?